# How to use one nic for storage traffic & other for network traffic in Linux(Slackware)?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, storage, slackware

**Problem** I have a Linux machine (Slackware) with two network interface cards and i want to use one interface for network traffic and other for storage traffic . As this is Slackware i dont know this this could be the solution or not but i am trying this : **ip route add IP1 dev eth0**, **ip route add IP2 dev eth1** For more reference please take a look at it[image]

Comment: Is the SAN directly connected to `eth1`? Are `eth0` and `eth1` connected to the same network? Do they have addresses in the same network?

Comment: @HaukeLaging SAN is directly connected to eth1 via iSCSI .Yes they have addresses in the same network .The only objective to do this is that I dont want any network traffic collision .

Comment: If the SAN is directly connected to `eth1` then you can change the addresses of `eth1` and the SAN so that they are outside the `eth0` subnet, can't you?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Actually I want SAN to be in the same network because I am only using a 8TB LUN of SAN mounted on Slackware .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bit complicated due to Linux being a "weak end system" design. Avoid it if you can.

Have a look at [this question on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/415304/multiple-physical-interfaces-with-ips-on-the-same-subnet).

If the ARP problems are solved (the traffic from the SAN to `eth1`) then all you still need should be a routing entry for the SAN:

```
# with then SAN address being 1.2.3.4 and the eth1 address 1.2.3.5
ip route add 1.2.3.4/32 dev eth1 src 1.2.3.5
```